# wp_insert_post let users post to without login...broke

Tags: posts, users

this question has been answered on stackoverflow.
here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321914/wp-insert-post-with-a-form/4321975#4321975

i'm trying to let users post to my site by using the `wp_insert_post()` function..

```
<?php $postTitle = $_POST['post_title'];
    $post = $_POST['post'];
    $submit = $_POST['submit'];

    if(isset($submit)){

        global $user_ID;

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $postTitle,
            'post_content' => $post,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_author' => $user_ID,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_category' => array(7,100)
        );

        wp_insert_post($new_post);

    }

?>
```

I got this hooked up to a form on a category page

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
<input type="text" name="post_title" size="45" id="input-title"/>

<textarea rows="5" name="post" cols="66" id="text-desc"></textarea> 


<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="7,100"/> 

<input class="subput round" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

I don't know what id did wrong..it's not working.
any ideas? thanks

Comment: actually thats me here it's correct on the actual file

Comment: What is the return value of `wp_insert_post()`? Could you add `var_dump()` around it? It returns the new ID if succesful, and a `WP_Error` on failure. The latter should contain an error message.

Comment: not successful and no error..just the same

Comment: A general cheap debugging tip: place `var_dump(__LINE__)` in the `wp_insert_post()` function, at various places, to find out until where the code executes. It should print out line numbers, and if it stops, you know the following `var_dump()` is not reached. Repeat as necessary to pinpoint the problem. We need more specific information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

wp_insert_post() makes use of the current user at several points, if memory serves.

So, you'd want to use wp_set_current_user() to switch that to some shared author user, and then switch it back to its original value when you're done.

Alternatively, require users to be logged in and allow all groups to create drafts.

Comment: it does not work even when i (admin) am logged in...confused

Answer (score 0):

One problem you have is

```
if(isset($submit)){
```

you declare $submit on line above

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
```

thats why

```
isset($submit)
```

always will return TRUE and execute your code.

I would although add

```
global $user_ID;
if ( $user_ID )
{
     //insert your post
}
else
{
     //give that person a message "Dude, you have to sign up or login to be able to submit content..."
}
```

Then skip the post_date and post_type with your values those get added anyways. The less you pass to that function the less you can do wrong...

I would try to add this to your e.g. function.php script

```
$new_post = array(
            'post_title' => 'Test Post Title',
            'post_content' => 'Test Post Content',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_author' => $user_ID,

        );
wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

This should insert a news post with the gioven values...
If this works the you know you have to look for the error in your form. I although think tht you cant pass categries to wp_insert_post....
But try the simple test first.

Comment: when i tested it in function.php it worked fine...but i'm still not sure why it't not working...i will look around